# My sub used to work for years but stopped working due to a - Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, variable-assignment

Both of my subs have recently stopped working out of the blue. This first function copies the contents of a .txt file, sorts them, and sends them to the appropriate tables., and I've no idea why it stopped working.

I can't seem to resolve the Issue since i use the code snippet from this sub multiple times and it works fine.. Code here
`

```
' Objective: Read txt files and extract information 

    
    For Each wksImport In wkbImbarq.Worksheets
            If StrComp(Left(wksImport.Name, 1), "R", vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then
                With tblDataBody
                
                    .gsInitializeWithValues wkbImbarq.Name, wksImport.Name, wksImport.Name & ".tbl"
                    .gsDeleteTableContent
                    .gsDeleteTableHeaderContent
                End With
                Set tblDataBody = Nothing
            End If
    Next wksImport
```

`

Comment: On which line do you get the error? Which object is not set (watch/local window)? How is this object dimensioned and assigned?

Comment: I got the error on the following  line: .gsDeleteTableContent

Comment: What object type is _tblDataBody_? Is _tblDataBody_ nothing in your line of error?

Comment: Set your error handling options to break in class module and try the code again. Then see which line is causing the error.